# RTL Snapshot test using React.createPoratl()

Tags: reactjs, react-testing-library

I have a simple component

```
import { createPortal } from 'react-dom';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';

const MyComponent = props => {
  const { isVisible } = props;

  if (isVisible) {
    return createPortal(<div className="my-component" />, document.getElementById('page'));
  }
  return null;
};

MyComponent.propTypes = {
  isVisible: PropTypes.bool,
};

export default MyComponent;
```

And its respective unit test:

```js
import React from 'react';
import { render, screen } from '@testing-library/react';
import '@testing-library/jest-dom';

import MyComponent from '../MyComponent';

const props = {
  isVisible: true,
};

describe('MyComponent', () => {
  it('Should match snapshot', () => {
    const page = document.createElement('div');
    page.setAttribute('id', 'page');
    document.body.appendChild(page);

    const { container } = render(<MyComponent {...props} />);
    screen.debug();
    expect(container.firstChild).toMatchSnapshot();
  });
});
```

But the snapshot file looks like this

```js
// Jest Snapshot v1, https://jestjs.io/docs/snapshot-testing

exports[`MyComponent Should match snapshot 1`] = `undefined`;
```

When the `screen.debug()` renders this:

```js
    <body>
      <div
        id="page"
      >
        <div
          class="mobileNavBg"
        />
      </div>
      <div />
    </body>
```

What am I missing, or doing wrong for the snapshot to be undefined?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're trying to snapshot the container returned by the render function from @testing-library/react. This container is a div that the library creates to render your component inside it, but since createPortal renders your component outside of this div, the snapshot of the container will not include your component's output.

Instead, you should snapshot the actual DOM node where your component is being rendered. Since you're rendering into a div with the id page, you should snapshot this node. Here's how you can adjust your test to correctly snapshot the output:

```js
import React from 'react';
import { render, screen } from '@testing-library/react';
import '@testing-library/jest-dom';

import MyComponent from '../MyComponent';

const props = {
 isVisible: true,
};

describe('MyComponent', () => {
 it('Should match snapshot', () => {
    const page = document.createElement('div');
    page.setAttribute('id', 'page');
    document.body.appendChild(page);

    render(<MyComponent {...props} />);

    // Instead of snapshotting the container, snapshot the actual DOM node where your component is rendered
    const portalTarget = document.getElementById('page');
    expect(portalTarget).toMatchSnapshot();
 });
});
```

https://react.dev/reference/react-dom/createPortal for more info.  The createPortal function is used to render children into a DOM node that exists outside the DOM hierarchy of the parent component. This means that when you're trying to snapshot the output, the test environment does not automatically capture the output rendered outside of its container.

Comment: Thank you, I found another way from a colleague to go about it `const { baseElement } = render(<MyComponent {...props} />);
      expect(baseElement.firstChild).toMatchSnapshot();`